# Google cloud projects are not listed up in google developer console for api access settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-developer-api

I'm following [Google Play Developer API guide](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started#using_an_existing_api_project) to link my google cloud project.

The guide doc says that I can choose the project I'd like to link from list. But in my play developer console, the list isn't shown up.

Instead there's a button to make new project in GooglePlay developer console - Settings - API access page. When I click on it, it creates new project at GCP and link my play developer console to it.

My account is owner of both, play developer console, google cloud.

What do I have to do to link my existing google cloud project with google play developer console?